# Symfony2 - call a controller from within a view

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I want to have a view call upon controllers from within it. Similar to C#.NET MVC 4.0.

In my view I may have:

- Header
- Admin navigation
- Normal navigation
- Page content ( divided into three parts, list of something, list of something else, main page content
- Footer

All of these parts are reusable sections. I'm most likely going to always have a Header, Normal nav and Footer part of my page.

My controller does database calls to fetch the model and pump it to my view.
I don't want to ever have to worry about this code again so I just want to call the result of this controller from any view: pseudo code:

**Template view: base.html.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title><?php $view['slots']->output('title', 'Welcome!') ?></title>
        <?php $view['slots']->output('stylesheets') ?>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('favicon.ico') ?>" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $view['actions']->render(SomethingBundle:Navigation:index); ?> // THIS LINE HERE
        <h1><?php $view['slots']->output('pageTitle') ?></h1>
        <?php $view['slots']->output('_content') ?>
    </body>
```

So this is my template page, and I expect to be able to include the navigation view in this page, but the navigation requires a model so it also depends on the navigation controller.

**Navigation controller: Controller/NavigationController**

```
class NavigationController extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            return $this->render(SomethingBundle:Navigation:index.html.php');
        }
    }
```

**Navigation View: index.html.php**

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

Obviously the above code does not work. How do you include the result of a controller in a view?

the error I get from the above code is:

```
[2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET Navigation:index"  -+  
[1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:   -+
```

Comment: No. No. No. No. This *completely* goes against the conventions of MVC. If you want your menu rendered by a controller, then use a helper instead; don’t try and call a controller from a view.

Comment: Why is this a helper? What if I have a navigation page that just shows the navigation... then a page that I want using the exact same navigation snippet.. There is absolutely no need for a separate concept here. I'm a massive fan of Ror and c#.net MVC 4.0 and this is how they operate. It's simple and makes complete sense. However, if you wish to answer with your alternative, i'll be happy to see how you sort it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $view['actions']->render(
    new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference(
        'YourBundle:NavigationController:index'
    )
) ?>
```

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'ControllerReference' not found in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\Something\FrameworkBundle\Resources\views\base.html.php line 13 - any ideas?

Comment: @JamesT how about giving with namespace? Replace `ControllerReference` with `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference`

Comment: Yes that works.. Oh gawd.. Okay is there a way to throw in the using somewhere so I do not need to reference such a butt ugly name everywhere? tidyup time?

Comment: Place this code piece into a resuable template, and include wherever you want.